# How to generate a random array for each iteration of a loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm trying to create a large number of arrays with random integers of similar size for each iteration of a loop. e.g 500 iterations.(So for each loop, a new array is created) Then sort these 500 arrays using my implemented sort methods. I'm pretty new to java and I don't even know where to start.
I have a random array method which inputs random variables into an array to help with inputting the variables

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See this code snippet helps you or not. Let me know.

```
private int[] getRandomArray(int size){
    int[] arr = new int[size];
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        //if you don't any bound
        int rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt();
        //if you need any bound. for example following will return int value in between 10 and 100
        //int rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10, 100);
        arr[i] = rand;
    }
    return arr;
}
```